# Can I reset the name of jQuery's global object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let me give my question some context. I have a JavaScript widget. The widget includes a copy of jQuery from my site. This widget is placed on a third-party site. The widget parses a JSON feed and injects the contents into the DOM. Pretty simple stuff.

If the third-party page already has jQuery referenced and relies on jQuery plugins, conflicts could arise. Especially, when the third-party site references a different version of jQuery. $.noConflict() is useful, but the existence of plugins make it unreliable. From the [$.noConflict() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/):

> If necessary, we can free up the
>   jQuery name as well by passing true as
>   an argument to the method. This is
>   rarely necessary, and if we must do
>   this (for example, if we need to use
>   multiple versions of the jQuery
>   library on the same page), we need to
>   consider that most plug-ins rely on
>   the presence of the jQuery variable
>   and may not operate correctly in this
>   situation.

To get around this issue, my idea is to reset the name of the jQuery global object. At the bottom of the jQuery source, there are these lines:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.jQuery = window.$ = jQuery;
```

Could I refactor the lines to:

```
// Expose jQuery to the global object
window.myjQuery = jQuery;
```

I've removed the shorthand $ variable, and I've changed jQuery to myjQuery. Now my code can look like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>myjQuery</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myjquery-1.4.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
      // .ready() can alias the jQuery object
      // I can pass $ and write code as normal
      myjQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('p').css('color', 'red');
      });

      // Fails
      jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $('p').css('color', 'blue');
      })

      // Fails
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('p').css('color', 'green');
      })

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>myjQuery changed my color to red.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this a good idea? I don't know the internals of the library enough to say for sure. I understand the library is basically a closure, so I'm guessing this approach is OK. Thoughts?

**EDIT:** I've accepted Doug's answer because he provided code which is almost identical to an example on the $.noConflict() documentation page. I didn't notice it before.  Here is the example:

```
// Completely move jQuery to a new namespace in another object.
var dom = {};
dom.query = jQuery.noConflict(true);

// Do something with the new jQuery
dom.query("div p").hide();

// Do something with another library's $()
$("content").style.display = 'none';

// Do something with another version of jQuery
jQuery("div > p").hide();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not normally a good idea to edit a released file if you don't need to. I read your question, and this solution will work for your needs. Don't edit the jQuery core at all. Do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Revert $ and jQuery to their original values:
  window.myjQuery = jQuery.noConflict(true);
  (function($){
    // Inside here, $ = myjQuery

    $(document).ready(function(){

    });
  })(window.myjQuery);
</script>
```

The important thing is for your widget to include jQuery, then **immediately** call `noConflict(true)` and store it in a variable.

If you follow these steps exactly, it will not affect existing jQuery instances or plugins on the page. It will only give you a private version of jQuery in the variable `myjQuery` for your own plugin.

Secondly, using a self executing anonymous function, you can create a private scope for your widget where `$` equals your included jQuery file.

Comment: Made a post saying it was okay if they needed it; like this solution better.

Comment: @simeonwillbanks Happy to help! I just noticed one thing more. Your script tag was using empty tag syntax: `<script ... />` and if I remember right, that causes problems in some browsers. Just use: `<script ...></script>` instead. Good luck with your widget!